# logstash grok parse user agent string parse certain fields

Tags: logstash, grok, logstash-grok

I have this UA in a log file
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2267.0 Safari/537.36`

Now all I really want is to grab things like `Windows NT 6.1` (i.e. win7) and `WOW64` i.e. 64 bit system.

My current grok filter parses all the things out and then runs a `remove field` afterwards to discard the unwanted things. Is there an easier/cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [useragent filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/useragent) to parse such fields.

```
filter {
  useragent {
    source => "field-with-useragent"
  }
}
```

It won't extract the WOW64 string, though, but I doubt it's very useful anyway (and I'm sure not all browsers provide it). That said, you could look for that string yourself with a conditional:

```
if [field-with-useragent] =~ /\bWOW64\b/ {
  mutate {
    add_tag => ["64bit"]
  }
}
```